# Event listener defined inside object

Tags: javascript

I recently saw a listener defined inside method of object bound to nothing. Nice example is this

```
var obj={
    shout:function(){
        onclick = function(){
            alert("hi");
        }
    }
}
obj.shout()
```

This works like window.onclick=shout;

also when we redefine function like this

```
var obj={
    shout:function(s){
        onclick = function(s){
            alert(s);
        }
    }
}
obj.shout('hi')
```

It outputs [Object mouse event]

How does it get automaticly binded to window object?  This should point to obj object and if onclick gets binded to `this` of shout which refers to `obj` (my suspicion ) how come it works with window object??

Comment: What you might think of as a global variable (here "obj" and "onclick") are actually properties of the global "window" object (in a browser).  That is, `var obj = foo;` is actually `window[obj] = foo;` aka `window.obj = foo;`

Comment: Err. `window["obj"] = foo;` that is. (too late to edit previous comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does it get automaticly binded to window object?

Because `onclick` is a property of `window`, and all properties of `window` are global variables. Since you haven't declared an `onclick` variable anywhere, the `onclick = function...` line is assigning to the global.

Answer (score 3):

*How does it get automaticly binded to window object?*

Because whenever you declare a variable without using `var` keyword, it will be assigned to the `window object`. So in our case you have assigned a `function` to `onclick` without specifying `var`, As a result the function got assigned with `window.onclick`.

And If you want to use the value passed via `constructor` function then for that you need to write a `closure`,

```
var obj={
    shout:function(s){
        onclick = function(){
        //-----------------^ remove the parameter here, and it will become a closure.
            alert(s);
        }
    }
}

obj.shout('hi');
```

Comment: *"Because whenever you declare a variable without using `var` keyword"* They aren't *declaring* the `onclick` variable at all. They're *using* it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah that line is a generic statement. But later I have explained it explicitly for `onclick`. And I accept, I didn't read the question fully. read it fully after receiving a downvote. Thanks for speaking out. :)